# Access Control within RowDetailsTemplate on SelectionChange of ComboBox

Tags: silverlight

I want to access a CheckBox in order to change it's enable/disable in a selectionChange event of a ComboBox. both controls are in a rowDetailsTemplate
My Example:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <sdk:DataGrid  AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn  Visibility="Collapsed">
            </sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <sdk:DataGrid  Width="Auto" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn >
                                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ComboBox Name="cbAction" SelectionChanged="cbAction_SelectionChanged" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn >
                                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate >
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                            <CheckBox Name="cbChaluka" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  IsEnabled="False" IsChecked="{Binding _LOGI_GOT,Mode=TwoWay}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
                                            </CheckBox>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                    </sdk:DataGrid>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

This is very important!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Small example...

```
private CheckBox cbChaluka = null;

private void datagridname_LoadingRowDetails(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
{
    cbChaluka = e.DetailsElement.FindName("cbChaluka");
}
```

then on the selectionchange event on your other control you can then reference cbChaluka.

Comment: Worked for me - this should be accepted as the answer

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why but in silverlight u can not access controls directly from code alternately in your case u can register load event of checkbox and onload u can store this object in code globally in some list and then access it from that global list. if u have more than one row then u have to add some type of unique identifier with each checkbox at time of load before adding it to a global list u can create a a unique guid and assign it to tag property of checkbox.

if u have any issue in this then plz let me know